# How to use shared libraries in a static library without forcing end-users to link against these?

Tags: c++, static-linking, dynamic-linking

Let's say I'm working on a static library `foo.a`, which makes use of a function in `bar.so`.

How do I build this library in such a way that anyone who uses `foo.a` in their project doesn't have to explicitly link against `bar.so`?

Comment: I know this is possible, because SFML doesn't require me to link -lX11 or -lGL.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, that you can't do this, unless you get a static library of `bar`, for your example - `bar.a` (as I already said in your other question, I just can't give more information, as I'm not familiarized with `SFML` or `XLib`)

Comment: What is your goal? Do you just want to avoid the reference to `bar.so` at link-time because that is more convenient? Or do you want to be able to swap out `bar.so` with `someother.so` without re-linking?

Comment: No, I want people to not need to link against -lGL, -X11 and any other dynamic library I need to use.

Comment: In that case, the `dlopen` mentioned by user315052 is an overkill IMO. What you gain is hardly worth the extra coding effort and maintainability issues. Better stick with the extra linker options, there is no easy way to avoid them.

Comment: And with regard to SFML, are you sure that your are not linking against some dynamic library which on its turn references `-lX11` and `-lGL`?

Comment: @Reinier: It is not overkill if the OP insists on static lib. More than likely, SFML is a shared library, and with shared libraries, you can specify the lib dependencies right on the link line when you build it. So, they get pulled in by the dynamic linker at load time. You can view what other shared libraries a shared library depends on with `ldd`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do in `libfoo.a` is make a call to `dlopen` to dynamically link `libbar.so`. Then, use `dlsym` to locate the function you want to use.

```
typedef void (*BarFunctionType) (const char *);
FunctionType barFunction;

void initialize_foo_lib () {
    void *h = dlopen("libbar.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    BarFunctionType barFunction = (BarFunctionType) dlsym(h, "barFunction");
    // Note scary looking cast to get your function pointer.
    //... rest of code can call barFunction now
}
```

`libbar.so` should be a C library, or the function should be `extern "C"` if a C++ library, for you to find the function name properly. Otherwise you will need to mangle the name to find the function with `dlsym`. You can use `objdump -T` on the library to check if the names in the library are mangled.

Realize there is still a dependency on `libbar.so`, but it is baked into your static library. So the user of `libfoo.a` does not have to add `-lbar` to the link line when they link in `-lfoo`.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the extensions, you are looking for a Unix way; to my knowledge, both g++ and clang++ can't do this.

Visual C++ can probably do it -- I've only used it for static libraries, not DLLs, but...